s-t max-flow and max-reward (min-cost) flow
I apologize if this question is duplicated.
Consider a bipartite graph with vertices separated into two sets $I$ and $J$, and two additional points $s$ and $t$. Connect directed edges from $s$ to all $i\in I$, from all $i\in I$ to all $j\in J$, and from all $j\in J$ to $t$.
The capacities on the edges are $c(s,i) = a_i$ for all $i\in I$, $c(j,t) = b_j$ for all $j\in J$, and $c(i,j) = \infty$ for all $i\in I$ and $j\in J$. Moreover, consider the "rewards" on the edges: $r(s,i) = 0$ for all $i\in I$, $r(j,t) = 0$ for all $j\in J$, and $r(i,j) = p_{ij} > 0$ for all $i\in I$ and $j\in J$.
Let the flow on edge $(u, v)$ be $f(u, v)$. Try to find an s-t flow such that the total reward, $\sum_{(u,v)\in E} r(u, v)\cdot f(u, v)$, is maximized.
My question is, is there exists a maximum s-t flow $f$ maximizes the total reward as well?
I know the answer is No in general. However, I think there are some good properties in this graph: (1) that the max-flow (min-cut) only associated to the $(s, i)$ and $(j, t)$ edges, while the total reward only associated to the $(i, j$) edges. (2) all the rewards are nonnegative. (3) the graph is acyclic and bipartite. My intuition says that the flow maximizing total reward may want to exhaust as many capacities as possible, as increasing flow is always better off. Therefore, one of my attempt is to prove by contradiction, but I can only argue the local optimality.
This is probably related to the min-cost max-flow considering costs as negative rewards. However, the min-cost max-flow problem restricted that the feasible solutions are max-flows, while I want to show that the optimal solution remains unchanged without the max-flow condition.
Assignment problem may be related as well, but the integer constraints are not imposed in my problem.
I also tried to construct a counterexample to disprove the problem, but I did not really find one.
Any thoughts, suggestions, or related works are appreciated!

Take a maximum  reward flow. If you have non saturated edges $su$ and $vt$, you can augment the flow on $uv$ without decreasing the reward. Repeat this until one of the side is saturated, you will have a maximum flow.
Here, you don't need any fancy algorithm, you can just use the greedy approach:
Take the edge $uv$ with maximal reward such that $su$ and $vt$ are not saturated, and push the maximum of flow. Repeat until you have a max flow.

Yes, I agree that this is a natural way to think about it, and it seems correct to me.
However, I still struggle with the following: Given a maximum reward flow, if we cannot augment more flow on the graph, how can we know there is no way to decrease the flow in one part of the graph (causing a reward decrease) and increase more flow elsewhere?
This idea feels intuitive, but I am unsure how to rigorously justify it :(

@teratogen_ Once we saturate all the edges on one of the sides of the graph, we can't possibly get a better max flow because we used the full potentiality of either the edges coming out of $s$ or entering $t$. More generally, the maximum flow can't exceed the sum of capacities of a given $st$-cut. An important result is that the maximum flow is always equal to the minimum $st$-cut.

I see where I missed! Thank you so much!
